# Explain this circuit to me

Tags: bjt

I have always found it very easy to design with dual supplies.This circuit uploaded by me is operating in active region because Vec=3V.Mostly in such circuits very negligible base current flows (don't know why).I find this very strange because the base current controls the collector current.On the contrary if I replace the negative battery (on the bottom right) with ground very large base current starts flowing.I can not understand why? [image]

Comment: Your base resistors are unrealistically low for most real applications. When this large current flows, what is the voltage between base and collector? Is the junction still reverse biased?

Comment: It definitely is...+1.30V at base and -1.07 at collector.

Comment: How are you getting a negative voltage with SRC2 = 0V? That makes no sense.

Comment: Oh sorry,I was talking with SRC2 present.

Comment: "I find this very strange because the base current controls the collector current". It is a "tragedy" but this false statement still can be found in some textbooks. But it is false. No problem to proove that Vbe controls Ic.

Comment: Ok.I agree with you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the negative supply disabled, i.e. with the collector resistor's lower leg grounded, you are driving the BJT in saturation. That's because in this circuit, due to R2 feedback, \$I_C\$ is essentially constant between the two situations. In fact the base divider is very stiff and provides about 1.4V at the base. Since \$V_{BE} \approx 0.7V\$ is essentially constant, the emitter voltage is ~2.1V. Hence the voltage across R2 is always 5V-2.1=~2.9V. Hence the current through R2 is always \$I_E \approx I_C \approx ~9mA\$, regardless of the negative supply.

That current must flow also through R4, giving rise to a ~2.2V drop across it. Sum this 2.2V with the 2.9V across R2 and you end up with less than 1V of \$V_{CE}\$: that means a saturated BJT.

With the negative supply present you have 5V more headroom to be spent across collector and emitter, hence the BJT remains in the active region, where the relation between \$I_C\$ and \$I_B\$ is linear (\$I_C = h_{FE} I_B\$) and \$I_B <<I_C\$.

In the saturation region \$I_C\$ doesn't depend on \$I_B\$ any longer and this latter is no longer a small fraction of the former.

**EDIT** (prompted by a comment)

Look at the [datasheet of the 2N3906](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N3906.pdf) (what you call \$\beta\$ is called \$h_{FE}\$ on datasheets):

[image]

with the negative supply connected the BJT operates in its active region and the relation between \$I_C\$ and \$I_B\$ is approximately linear, as I already said above. If you invert that relation you get:

$$
I_B = \dfrac{I_C}{h_{FE}} \approx \dfrac{9mA}{300} \approx 30 \mu A << I_C = 9 mA
$$

If you don't understand or know what the different [operating regions of a BJT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Regions_of_operation) you should [review your basics about BJTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor).

Comment: My question is:with the negative supply it is operating in active mode.Still Ic=beta*Ib does not work.Why is it so?

Comment: @muhammadmuheeb No, that was not your question. Reread your own post: `if I replace the negative battery (on the bottom right) with ground very large base current starts flowing.I can not understand why? ` And you say nothing in the post about the relative values of Ib and Ic. So if you want better answers provide better informations in your question, or formulate it better.

Comment: @muhammadmuheeb BTW, was your circuit only simulated or did you actually build it?

Comment: I am so sorry.Yes I admit that was not my question.But I did mention that very small base current flows and I don't understand why.Can you please explain that to me?

Comment: @muhammadmuheeb I explained it: with the negative supply connected the BJT works in its active region, i.e. Ib is much smaller than Ic because the DC voltage gain \$\beta=h_{FE}\$ is big (at least 100 and typically 300 for 2N3906 at 10mA of Ic - see datasheet).

Comment: I "accidently" built it.With dual supplies it always happens like that (base current is very small,so I neglect it and I can control my collector current by assuming Vb-Ve=0.7,for example here I assumed Ve=-0.3V implying that I should provide 0.4V at the base which as you can see I did(again I assumed zero base current while solving voltage divider).And since Ve=-0.3 I can find my emitter current which in turn will be equal to my collector current (again because the base current is low).Though I can not figure out why base current is low.

Comment: I understand everything but who would tell me when to ignore the base current and when to take it into account?

Comment: Although the base current does not control Ic - it does exist, of course. No doubt about it. The base current is a certain (small) part of the current that goes through the resistor R3. (Note: I didn´t check the VALUES of your circuit). Hence, this current must be taken into account for calculating the voltage divider at the base node.

Answer (score 0):

Base current is low because the impedance of a common collector amplifier is usually pretty high. When you saturate it is not a common collector amplifier anymore, and therefore, impedance drops.